# Moving final classes to another package without breaking binary compatibility

Tags: java, refactoring, binary-compatibility

So, I have a singleton class that is `final` and `Serializable` exposed as part of the public API of my library and I want to move into another package, hopefully without breaking binary compatibility. My set up looks somewhat like this:

```
package a;

public final class MyApi implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUid = 1L;
  private static final MyApi instance = new MyApi();

  public static MyApi getInstance() { return instance; }

  private MyApi() {}

  private Object readResolve() { return instance; }
}
```

In order to move it into another package, I removed final modifier from the class and make its primary constructor public. Then in my new package, I extended that class and redirected all of the static fields in the original class to a new instance. And as a final step I made the original constructor throw if this class is not an instance of a new class (This is the part that I'm not sure of mostly):

```
package a;

@Deprecated
public class MyApi implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUid = 1L;

  public static MyApi getInstance() {
    return b.MyApi.getInstance();
  }

  public MyApi() {
    if (!getClass().equals(b.MyApi.class) {
      throw new AccessControlException("Historical alias. Extension is prohibited.") 
    }
  }

  private Object readResolve() {
    return b.MyApi.getInstance()
  }
}

package b;

public final class MyApi extends a.MyApi {
  private static final long serialVersionUid = 1L;
  private static final MyApi instance = new MyApi();

  public static MyApi getInstance() { return instance; }

  private MyApi() {}

  private Object readResolve() { return instance; }
}
```

My question to you is: do you think it's a reasonable approach? Is it actually binary compatible or there's something in this setup that will not be compatible? Is there a way to make it better?